# gdb debugging segmentation fault, arguments count showing false

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am trying to debug the segmentation fault of a menu program written in 'C' and the main function is shown in the below screen shot.

```
int main( int ac, char **av ) {


/* TDT,II - 02 May 2006 - Added this check to see if there is a Debug level passed in */
    if ( ac > 0 ) {
        iDebug = atoi( av[1] );
        sprintf( cLogText, "Setting Debug Level to ~%d~", iDebug );
        WriteTrace( cLogText );
    };

    initscr();
    clear();

    t1=time(NULL);
    local =localtime(&t1);
    Svc_Login();

    for ( ; ; ) {
        cases_on_pc=FALSE;
        if ( !Process_security() ) break;
        menu1();
    };

    wrap_up(0);
    endwin( );
    exit(0);
}
```

when i try to debug (run using gdb), without any arguments, getting halted at `0x00007ffff34c323a in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6` as shown below. `if(ac>0)` becomes true, only when i pass any arguments. but i haven't passed any runtime arguments. still that 'f block is being executed and function `atoi(av[1])` is called and resulted in segmentation fault. I am unable to figure it out. how to proceed further to identify and correct the issue so that i could run the menu program successfully. could somebody give any suggestions on this?

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 MaheshRedhat MaheshRedhat 2275270 Jan 10 03:09 caomenu.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 MaheshRedhat MaheshRedhat       0 Jan 10 03:09 caomenu.lis
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root         root          796104 Jan 10 03:10 scrmenu
[MaheshRedhat@azureRHEL MenuPrograms]$
[MaheshRedhat@azureRHEL MenuPrograms]$ gdb ./scrmenu

(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/MaheshRedhat/MenuPrograms/scrmenu
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff34c323a in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: yum debuginfo-install glibc-2.28-189.5.0.1.el8_6.x86_64 libnsl-2.28-189.5.0.1.el8_6.x86_64 ncurses-libs-6.1-9.20180224.el8.x86_64
(gdb) 
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff34c323a in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff34bfce4 in atoi () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000401674 in main (ac=1, av=0x7fffffffe228) at caomenu.pc:541
(gdb)
```

**Update**
The above issue has been resolved. Here is another encounter of segmentation fault.
from  this backtrace of system calls, in `WriteTrace (cEntryText=0x6f4d20 <cLogText>` in my main function lead to call fputs() from library file `/lib64/libc.so.6`

```
Starting program: /home/MaheshRedhat/MenuPrograms/scrmenu 1
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff34f7f5c in fputs () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff34f7f5c in fputs () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000472efc in WriteTrace (cEntryText=0x6f4d20 <cLogText> "Setting Debug Level to ~1~") at caomenu.pc:18394
#2  0x00000000004016a0 in main (ac=2, av=0x7fffffffe208) at caomenu.pc:543
(gdb)
```

The below is the declaration of `cLogText`

```
char        cLogText[250];
```

The below is code for WriteTrace:

```
/**************************************************************************
 routine to write an entry in the trace file
 **************************************************************************/
void WriteTrace( char *cEntryText ) {

    char cTimeStamp[40];                         /* time stamp variable */
    char cTimeFormat[]="%H:%M:%S: ";             /* time stamp format */

    GetTimeStamp( &cTimeStamp[0], sizeof(cTimeStamp), &cTimeFormat[0] );
    TrcFile = fopen( cTraceFile, cTrcOpenFlag ); /* open the file */
    cTrcOpenFlag[0] = 'a';                       /* after first, always app} */
    fprintf(TrcFile, "%s",   cTimeStamp);        /* write the time stamp */
    fprintf(TrcFile, "%s\n", cEntryText);        /* write the entry */
    fclose(TrcFile);                             /* close the trace file */
    return;                                      /* return to caller */
}
```

Comment: What is ```WriteTrace```? What's ```clogText```?

Comment: What is ```CtraceFile```? What is ```cTrcopenflag```?

Comment: `GetTimeStamp( &cTimeStamp[0], sizeof(cTimeStamp), &cTimeFormat[0] );` This is basically correct but uncommon. These arrays already decay to pointers when passed to a function. Instead you can write `GetTimeStamp( cTimeStamp, sizeof(cTimeStamp), cTimeFormat);` which is more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C11:

> The value of argc shall be nonnegative. **argv[argc] shall be a null
> pointer.** If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members
> argv[0] through argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to
> strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host
> environment prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the
> program information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere
> in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
> supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the
> implementation shall ensure that the strings are received in
> lowercase.

> **If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string
> pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name;** argv[0][0] shall be
> the null character if the program name is not available from the host
> environment. **If the value of argc is greater than one, the strings
> pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program
> parameters.**

The condition
`( ac > 0 )`
would be true even if you provided `0` program arguments, with `argv[0]` pointing to the program name (if it was available).

This statement:

```
atoi( av[1] );
```

tries to access `av[1]` which the Standard defines to be `NULL` when no program arguments were provided. Hence the segmentation violation signal.

---

`fopen` returns `NULL` to indicate failure.

```
TrcFile = fopen( cTraceFile, cTrcOpenFlag );
```

You do not check its return value here, before passing it to `fprintf`.

Perhaps:

```
TrcFile = fopen( cTraceFile, cTrcOpenFlag );
if (!TrcFile) {
    deal with error here..
}
```

Comment: thankyou @Haris , Now it's working in this aspect. I have encountered another segmentation fault for fputs() call from library. I have updated my question. Could you Please check once

Comment: There's no call to ```fputs``` in the code you provided us with. Kindly edit the question to include a minimal reproducible example containing all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ac > 0) {
 iDebug = atoi(av[1]);  // out of bounds here, when you run `./scrmenu`
}
```

when you run `./scrmenu`, you will have `ac=1` and `av[0]=./scrmenu`

You may misunderstand `ac` and `av` mean in the `main` function.

how to fix:

```
if (ac == 2) {
 iDebug = atoi(av[1]);  // parse the second argument
}
```

then you can run: `./scrmenu` or `./scrmenu 1` something like this.

you can check this post about [command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: thankyou @TiapingHsu. Now it's working in this aspect. I have encountered another segmentation fault for fputs() call from library. I have updated my question. Could you Please check once